# Is it correct to use "no?" after a question to get some kind of confirmation

Tags: grammaticality, pronunciation, question-tags, intonation

> We are going to the club tonight, no?

Is it correct?

Comment: It depends entirely on the intonation of the _no_. If the intonation is correct, so is the grammar; if not, not. Tag questions are more complicated, but much more common.

Answer (score 0):

The tag question would be more favorable:

> We are going to the club tonight, aren't we?

Considering the pronunciation:

a) If we don't know the answer, it is a real question and we use a rising intonation with the tag question.

b)If we know the answer and are just confirming the information we use a falling intonation with the tag question.

(Source: http://www.eslbase.com/grammar/tag-questions)

However, since it is the spoken context, your way is ok, but the pause before *no* should occur.

Answer (score 0):

I would not say it is correct but it is used by most non-english speaking people to communicate 'we are going to the club, aren't we?'

I would say in its original form it becomes more of conclusive question to indicate we are not going. In order to get the answer from the person to whom this question is being aimed at at least it should say 'we are going to the club, yes or no?' Then the other person can answer with yes or no.